# Beginner cucumber query-How to create a feature file after installing cucumber eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cucumber

After installing cucumber eclipse plugin from the link http://mrpotes.github.com/cukes-jvm-eclipse-plugin/update-site, I have restarted eclipse and have been trying to create a cucumber feature file .

I am trying to create my first feature. But when I select `File - New - Project` or `File - New - Other`, I cannot see cucumber feature listed so that I can select and create a feature file.

Please help me with the steps to create a cucumber feature file in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that plugin, but a feature file is just a text file, why don't you create one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of Eclipse in which "Install New Software" (Help->Install New Software..) option is available. In that do the following steps:

1. Help->Install New Software..
2. Install window will open, in that window click Add button
3. Add Repository window will open, in that type the following
   Name     : Cucumber
   Location : http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site
4. Click OK

After restarting the eclipse you can create feature files.